# Read and replace URL from PDF file

Tags: java, beginner, url, pdf

This is a code I wrote to find all URL within a PDF file and replace the one that matches the ID that I passed as a parameter.

It works as intended, but as I am a beginner on Java, I am sure there are some best practices that I am not following.

I am using the PDFBox library.

Here's the code:

Main.java

```
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length < 4) {
        System.err.println("Parameter missing from PHP");

    } else {
        Helper.getURL(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);
    }

}
}
```

Helper.java

```
public class Helper {

public static void getURL(String oldreportid, String newreportid, String oldpdf, String newpdf) {
    PDDocument doc = null;

    try {
        doc = PDDocument.load(oldpdf);
        List allPages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        for (int i = 0; i < allPages.size(); i++) {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) allPages.get(i);
            List annotations = page.getAnnotations();
            for (int j = 0; j < annotations.size(); j++) {
                PDAnnotation annot = (PDAnnotation) annotations.get(j);
                if (annot instanceof PDAnnotationLink) {
                    PDAnnotationLink link = (PDAnnotationLink) annot;
                    PDAction action = link.getAction();
                    if (action instanceof PDActionURI) {
                        PDActionURI uri = (PDActionURI) action;
                        String oldURL = uri.getURI();

                        String reportID = oldURL.substring(oldURL.lastIndexOf("=") + 1, oldURL.length());
                        if (oldreportid.equals(reportID)) {
                            String newURI = "http://www.test.com/test.php?T=MQ==&F=" + newreportid;
                            System.out.println("Page " + (i + 1) + ": Replacing " + oldURL + " with " + newURI);
                            uri.setURI(newURI);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        doc.save(newpdf);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (COSVisitorException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (doc != null) {
            try {
                doc.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Naming

1. `Helper`, although very common, is too generic as class name. Imagine it in a package with two dozens of other classes, how would you have a hint on what it is supposed to do by browsing the package? If it was named something like `PdfAnalyzeHelper` or `PdfProcessingHelper`, that would be better.
2. Looking at the name of the method `getURL(args)`, I was expecting to find a return value instead of `void`, which was confusing. The prefix `get*` in method names is often used for getters. Since this method does not return anything and executes some URL processing, that should be called, for example, `replaceReportIdInUrls(args)`.

#### SRP

The [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) seems to be violated in this method. I see three distinct things done:

1. Loading a PDF file.
2. Reading the file and replacing values in URLs.
3. Saving a new PDF file.

I'd suggest to split it into three distinct methods. It will be easier to maintain and reuse, if this is intended. Or, since the I/O with `PDDocument` is very concise, remove it from the method body and change the signature to

```
public static PDDocument replaceReportIdInUrls(PDDocument doc, 
                                               String reportIdOld,
                                               String reportIdNew);
```

#### `try-with-resources`

The I/O with `finally { doc.close(); }` is plain old before-Java-7 style. It can be simplified for

```
try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(oldpdf)) {
     // method body
} catch (IOException | COSVisitorException e) {
     // multicatch is also helpful!
}
```

This shortens the method for at least 12 lines!

#### Generics

The [version of PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.10/javadocs/) that you use seems to be a legacy one, `PDDocumentCatalog.getAllPages()` somehow returns an unbound `List`.
In order to (at least) avoid compilation warnings, type bounds should be added, for example:

```
List<?> allPages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
```

According to the javadoc, the list should contain `PDPage` objects, so if you dare rely on it, you can try a cast to `List<PDPage>`.

The same comment concerns the next `List` of annotations. Strangely, [the javadoc](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.10/javadocs/) describes it as typed, so only `<PDAnnotation>` should be added to the declaration.

#### `For` Loops

The `j` index of the inner loop is not reused, so it would be simpler to rewrite the loop:

```
for (PDAnnotation annotation : annotations) { ... }
```

and this will make useless the call `annotations.get(j);`

The same is about the outer loop, but since the `i` index is reused for the output, it can be kept.

#### Validation

The line

```
String reportID = oldURL.substring(oldURL.lastIndexOf("=") + 1, oldURL.length());
```

is not secured against the case when the URL does not contain the "=" character. `oldURL.lastIndexOf("=")` may return -1, in such case a [StringIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) will be thrown.

By the way, no validation at all is done for the method input params. What happens if one of them is `null` or empty?

Comment: Thank you for you VERY thorough answer, I will take my time during this week to properly read and implement those tips, and will update on the progress. You made very good points and I agree with all of them.

I have added Main.java to OP, please have a look